# embedding local html page with streamlit componets

Tags: python, streamlit

I am building a simple streamlit app with several pages. In one of the pages i want to display an embeded html and I am using iframe html.

```
import streamlit as st
import streamlit.components.v1 as components

components.iframe("mypage.html")
```

I get the following error message when I run my streamlit app.

*You have requested page /mypage.html, but no corresponding file was found in the app's pages/ directory. Running the app's main page.*

I have tried putting mypage.html file both in pages directory and in main directory of the app, but I still get the error message when I run the streamlit app. All examples I could find online are about embedding web page that already exists somehere on the internet, but I want to display an html I created. I am using
Python 3.9.15
streamlit                 1.17.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it turns out iframe can only take as an argument an URL. Instead  the whole HTML of the page I want to embed needs to be in done like this.

```
components.html("""
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
etc...
""")
```

Then it will work.